# VSCode Search Replace RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, search, replace, visual-studio-code

I am flatting an Angular translation file and I need to do a search replace in VScode on the translate key.  I need to clip off all that comes before the final key and return that to the replace. The keys will only be at most 3 levels deep.  The words below of `key and keepThisInReplace` are arbitrary and will be different words.  Examples below.

Search String Options:

```
'key1.keepThisInReplace1' | translate
'key1.key2.keepThisInReplace2' | translate
'key1.key2.key3.keepThisInReplace3' | translate
'anyWord.AndLevelAmount.UpTo3AtLeast.anyWordToKeep' | translate
```

Do not find in search:

```
'../../assets/images/
'./../assets/images/
'.......
'path').join
'staging.site
etc...
```

The above should be replaced as:

```
'keepThisInReplace1' | translate
'keepThisInReplace2' | translate
'keepThisInReplace3' | translate
'anyWordToKeep' | translate
```

What I am trying that is not working - Looks like '\w[^.]*.*\w*.*\w*. will work. will almost work - picks up on 'path').join and 'staging.site still.

The keys above all do have `{{` in front of them.  But if I lock in on the {{ then I have to return it in the replace.  Example = `{{ key1.key2.keeptext | translate }}` = `{{ keeptext | translate }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a non capturing group with a quantifier that repeats 1 - 3 times 1+ word characters followed by a dot and make sure multi line is enabled using the anchors `^$`.

In the replacement use a `'`

```
^'(?:\w+\.){1,3}(?=\w+'\s+\|\s+translate$)
```

If the string can be anywhere in the file your could omit the anchors and use a word boundary `\b` after translate.

```
'(?:\w+\.){1,3}(?=\w+'\s+\|\s+translate\b)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:\w+\.){1,3}` Repeat 1 - 3 times matching 1+ word chars and a dot
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is

  - `\w+'\s+` Match 1+ word chars, `'` and 1+ whitespace chars
  - `\|` Match `|`
  - `\s+translate$` Match 1+ whitespace chars, `translate` and assert end of the string
- `)` Close positive lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UhnLIE/1)

Another option instead of a positive lookahead is using 2 capturing groups.

In the replacement use group 1 and group 2 `$1$2`

```
^(')(?:\w+\.){1,3}(\w+'\s+\|\s+translate$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k9AdCY/1)

Comment: No because or else you have to use 2 capturing groups to keep the second single quote `^(')(?:\w+\.){1,3}(\w+)(')\s*\|\s*translate$` See https://regex101.com/r/O6xFpb/2

Comment: I was just asking because you edited your answer to add it 30 seconds after I did

Comment: Ah, I see. That was not intentionally. I was making the pattern more specific and then updated it.

Comment: ah ok gotcha, well we ended up with pretty similar answers but yours is more specified.  although with the lookahead, the rest seems kind of overkill which is why I changed it back to `'.+\.`

Comment: by the way, you might want to mention that yours only works if multi line enabled, otherwise `^` and `$` won't work

Comment: @Thefourthbird  I biffed on the find/replace - forgot to put the ' in it.  Here is another regex question that hopefully you can help on - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56707400/regex-return-found-group-if-string-does-not-start-with-vscode

Answer (score 0):

`'.*\.` to `'` should be all you need. This will replace all strings that match a tick followed by any number of characters and then a dot.

if you want to be more specific you can use this

```
'\w*\.*\w*\.*\w*\.
```

this will match up to 3 dots with words in between.

Check the demo here: https://regexr.com/4g652

**EDIT**

I tried to make it more specific and here is what I came up with:

```regex
'.+\.(?=\w*'\s*\|\s*translate)
```

This uses a lookahead to make sure the matched string is followed by a word and then `' | translate`.  Do you think this is specific enough?

Demo: https://regexr.com/4g66i

Comment: good point on the not really needing to return the value.  The only issue I am seeing is that '.. and '. are being returned too. Example for relative locations - '../../assets/images/ and './../assets/images/

Comment: And I guess '.../ '......../ would too - not that I see those happening, but the more defined the regex search = the safer.

Comment: Looks like '\w[^\.]*\.*\w*\.*\w*\. will almost work - picks up on 'path').join and 'staging.site still.

Comment: I edited my answer, I think this should basically guaranteed match only what you're looking for!  let me know if it does not