# RegEx Return found Group IF String Does NOT start with ' - VSCode - Search/Replace

Tags: regex, regex-group

So, I did a global undoable RegEx search and replace.  I forgot to include the `'` in the replace.  Now I need to do a search on strings that match the below.  It must not start with a `'` and will have `| translate` at the end.  These are Angular translation keys - they can be all over in the template file (HTML). They always begin with {{, have | translate,  and end with }}.  Now the kicker is they could have spacing or line break issues (less likely but a chance).  So it could be {{_ _ textToKeepAdd'To _ _ | _ _ translate _ _ }} The _ _ being spaces or a line break possibility.

Strings To Match (no beginning '):

```
anyText' | translate

<other text or tags>{{ anyText' | translate

{{  // line break
anyText' | translate

anyText'
 | translate // line break
```

Strings Not To Match:

```
'anyText' | translate

 <other text or tags>{{ 'anyText' | translate

'anyText'
 | translate
```

Return String Format:

```
'anyText' | translate
```

Example:

```
blahadskfjlksjdf' | translate = 'blahadskfjlksjdf' | translate

'SkipMe' | translate = not found for replacement bc it starts with a '.

And <other text or tags>{{ anyText' | translate =  <other text or tags>{{ 'anyText' | translate
```

Here is the code that I biffed on - `'(?:\w+\.){1,3}(?=\w+'\s+\|\s+translate\b)`

I am going to need a group capturing/returning in the replace.

Comment: Try `^(?!').*'[\s\n]+\| translate$` and replace with `'$0`. See https://regex101.com/r/8mMH8E/1

Comment: Or, `^(?!')(.*')[\s\n]+(\| translate)\b` =>  `'$1 $2`, see https://regex101.com/r/8mMH8E/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

**Replace** `\{\{(?:\s|\n)*(?!(?:'|\s|\n))(.*')(?:\s|\n)*(\|(?:\s|\n)+translate)\b`

**with** `{{ '$1 $2`

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rTYKPb/2)

**Explanation:**

- `\{\{` - match two open braces
- `(?:\s|\n)*` - match any number of whitespace characters
- `(?!(?:'|\s|\n))(.*')` - capture group 1; match any continuous string of not `'` characters followed by a single `'`
- `(?:\s|\n)*` - match any number of whitespace characters
- `(\|(?:\s|\n)+translate)` - capture group 2; match `|` followed by at least one, or more, whitespace character and then the word `translate`.
- `\b` - match a word boundary

Comment: No, `\s` in VSCode does not match line breaks and OP mentions there may be a line break before `|`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the note. Updated the answer

Comment: `\n` matches any kind of line break in VSCode. You do not need `\r?\n`. Besides, your solution will keep the linebreak, I think OP does not want to keep it in the output.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew fixed

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew he did not specify that. but i will include it

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath This doesn't work bc it will put the ' at the beginning of $1 So... <other text or tags>{{ anyText' | translate = '<other text or tags>{{ anyText' | translate rather then <other text or tags>{{ 'anyText' | translate.

Comment: @RooksStrife you did not specify that there would be other text before the string. I need to know if the string preceding the second apostrophe will be alphanumeric

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath these are Angular translation keys - they can be all over in the template file (HTML)   The always begin with {{, have | translate,  and end with }}.  Now the kicker is they could have spacing or line break issues (less likely but a chance).  So it could be {{_ _ textToKeepAdd'To _ _ | _ _ translate _ _ }} The _ _ being spaces or a line break possibility.

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath VSCode is tossing an error of pcre2: error compiling pattern at offset 24: unmatched closing parenthesis.

Comment: @RooksStrife VSCode does not support look behinds or lazy operators. See my update

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath still getting the same error in VSCode with all of them.  Including the last one - \{\{[\s\n]*([^']*)'[\s\n]+(\|[\s\n]*translate)\b

Comment: @RooksStrife did you get an error using the expression without parentheses?

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath I put it in as it is displayed.

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath has something to do with the [\n\s]  If I do one or the other I get results, but both together in that [ ] = error.

Comment: @RooksStrife try now

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath almost perfect now.  It runs, but anyText' <line break>
 | translate is missed.  I take that back - I am an idiot... forgot the {{

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using

**Find What**:      `\{\{[\s\n]*(?!['\s\n])(.*')[\s\n]*(\|[\s\n]+translate)\b`
**Replace With**: `{{ '$1 $2`

See [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EkrVQp/2) (altered to reflect how it works in VSCode).

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `\{\{` - a `{{` substring
- `[\s\n]*` - 0+ whitespaces/linebreaks
- `(?!['\s\n])` - a negative lookahead failing the match if immediately to the right of the current location there is a `'` or a whitespace (linebreak included)
- `(.*')` - Capturing group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible and then a `'` char
- `[\s\n]*` - 0+ whitespaces/linebreaks
- `(\|[\s\n]+translate)\b` - Group 2: a `|`, 1+ whitespaces/linebreaks and a whole word `translate`.

The replacement is `'`, Group 1 backreference (referring to the value captured in Group 1), space and Group 2 backreference (referring to the value captured in Group 2).

Comment: This doesn't work bc it will put the ' at the beginning of $1 So... <other text or tags>{{ anyText' | translate = '<other text or tags>{{ anyText' | translate rather then <other text or tags>{{ 'anyText' | translate.

Comment: @RooksStrife You have changed the question altogether. I updated with a clean and explained solution.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew great answer. I think `[\s\n]` was causing issues for him which is why I used `(?:\s|\n)` instead. He definitely did switch up the question.

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath Thanks, I am sure `[\s\n]` should not cause issues, just tested in the latest 1.35.1 build.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew he might have been using an older build. He said it was throwing regex compilation errors when he tried doing any combination of `[\s\n]` in a character class

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath I have not heard of such issues. Perhaps, it is also related to `ripgrep` (in old versions) or `Use PCRE2` (in newer) options.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes he reported: "VSCode is tossing an error of pcre2: error compiling pattern at offset 24: unmatched closing parenthesis"

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath Then it is a typo on their part: `[\s\n]` has no paretheses.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have no clue. He said he copy pasted it in as is? Otherwise I would have written i more concisely